# Need assistance with queries for my tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically, I've populated all of my tables and now I want to create some queries for the user to find things easier.

This is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
select margin_id, pruce, client_uname
from margin
inner join claint
on price = claint_Iid
where claint.claint_id = 20;
```

When I type this code in it says that it's an empty set. However, when I select all from the invoice table, it has something that the client_id is 20, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: `price = client_fname`.  I can't imaging a data structure where equating columns with these names makes sense.  If you want help with your queries, then provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hey, you probably thought:
invoice inner join client on invoice.client_id = client.client_id ?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Always you can, use `indixes` in `join` clause

```
select invoice_id, price, client_fname
from invoice
inner join client
on invoice.client_id = client.client_id
where client.client_id = 20;
```